# Send a character to subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, omxplayer

I'm trying to control omxplayer on the command line on my rpi3 using a python script, I call subprocess.Popen and to control it (eg. play/pause, increase/decrease volume, etc..) I should write a character to stdin (eg. p, +/-, etc..), the character is passed in send_signal as variable text, using communicate I can't control it, is there a better way?

EDIT: Also player.stdin.write(text); player.stdin.flush() doesn't work.

```
def start_music():
    player = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', songs[0]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return player

def send_signal(player, text):
    player.communicate(text.encode('utf-8'))
    player.stdin.close()
```

trying with cat -e instead of omxplayer the output is:

```
why_dont_you work
test_input
test_input$
test_input2
test_input2$
a
a$
```

note that the first line somehow is not shown again

Comment: Is omxplayer a GUI or command-line program?

Comment: @NickT on the command line

Comment: Have you tried `player.stdin.write(text); player.stdin.flush()`?

Comment: @HaiVu Yes, also that doesn't work

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "doesn't work"? Does the other process not get that character written into stdin?

Comment: @syntonym The process starts and the music is played but if I try to pause it (or send another command) nothing happens

Comment: @kknickkk Can you try `cat -e` instead of `omxplayer`? That should just give you the characters you write to stdin back. I would guess omxplayer tries to communicate with the terminal (which fails, because there is no terminal). Maybe print out stdout/stderr and look for errors?

Comment: added the output in the question @syntonym

Comment: @kknickkk What should it print, i.e. what should have been the first line?

Comment: Add ` bufsize=0` to `Popen` parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Need to specify that what you're passing is the input variable i.e.

```
def send_signal(player, text):
    player.communicate(input=text.encode('utf-8'))
    player.stdin.close()
```

Comment: `input` is the default meaning of the first argument, so this is exactly identical to the OP's original code.